# Does Firefox not support position: relative?

Tags: css, firefox

I have a div, below is its css

```
#sign_up_box_1 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 280px;
    position:relative;
    top: -290px;
}
```

It works fine in safari, but does not work in Firefox.

Firefox seems to ignore the top:-290px.

can anyone help me?

below is the JSFiddle code:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    -moz-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    display: -moz-box;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 0;
}

#test {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
}
```

it works well in safari and chrome..but failed in firefox

I find the problem is at "box"...when I remove box property, firefox works fine...

Does anyone has some idea?

Comment: Can you show a JSFiddle example? What does it look like in FF?

Comment: Firefox certainly supports `position:relative` let us see a minimal code example of what you're trying to do and what is actually happening.

Comment: I can assure you `position: relative` works perfectly in Firefox. Give as more code and a screenshot or a live example as Pekka suggests.

Comment: I have added the JSFiddle example to my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative positioning of children of XUL boxes is not supported in Gecko.  It really doesn't make any sense to do that sort of thing in the XUL box model.

As long as you stick to using standard CSS, of course, relative positioning will work as expected.